# MySQL: Multiple Primary Keys and Auto Increment

Tags: mysql, auto-increment, composite-primary-key

I'm quite new to setting up tables in MySQL and there is something I'd like to do which is a bit more advance than I'm able to do.

I have two columns as part of a composite primary key, one is a Date and  an ID I would like to be an auto increment integer. For each date, I would like to reset the auto integer to 0, so something like this:

```
|-----------------|
|Date       | ID  |
|-----------------|
|2012-06-18 | 1   |
|2012-06-18 | 2   |
|2012-06-18 | 3   |
|2012-06-19 | 1   |
|2012-06-19 | 2   |
|2012-06-20 | 1   |
|-----------------|
```

Thanks

Comment: Auto increment does not work that way. So you will have to insert such records manually to have incremented number for each date.

Comment: See my answer below, it will work for MyISAM, not InnoDB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a before insert trigger.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `composite_auto_increment` BEFORE INSERT ON `your_table`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE max_id INT(11); -- add the appropriate column length from your table definition
    SELECT ID FROM `your_table` WHERE `Date` = DATE(NOW()) INTO max_id;
    SET NEW.ID = IF(ISNULL(max_id), 1, max_id + 1);
END$$
```

This way, if and ID already existed for the day, it gets incremented. If it didn't, it gets set to 1. Note that in this scenario, ID isn't `AUTO_INCREMENT` in the table definition. It just gets done by the trigger.

Comment: This is wrong, you need to lock the table before getting the max value. If you don't, 2 triggers that run at the same time will get the same identifier

Comment: Well, in MyISAM, inserts don't run concurrently. In InnoDB, you can lock. Good point though.

Answer (score 6):

Here this should work.

```
CREATE TABLE  `answer`(
  `dates` DATE NOT NULL,
  `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`dates`,`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

It is known to cause problems with innoDB. Hope this helps you.

EDIT: RESULTS

```
2012-06-19  1
2012-06-19  2
2012-06-19  3
2012-07-19  1
2012-07-19  2
2012-08-19  1
```

On php myadmin.

Answer (score 5):

Well, for me mysql does what you want automatically.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE TestData(Date date not null, ID int unsigned not null auto_increment, PRIMARY KEY(Date, ID));

mysql> INSERT INTO TestData SET Date = "2012-06-18";
mysql> INSERT INTO TestData SET Date = "2012-06-18";
mysql> INSERT INTO TestData SET Date = "2012-06-18";
mysql> INSERT INTO TestData SET Date = "2012-06-19";
mysql> INSERT INTO TestData SET Date = "2012-06-19";
mysql> INSERT INTO TestData SET Date = "2012-06-20";

mysql> select * from TestData;
+------------+----+
| Date       | ID |
+------------+----+
| 2012-06-18 |  1 |
| 2012-06-18 |  2 |
| 2012-06-18 |  3 |
| 2012-06-19 |  1 |
| 2012-06-19 |  2 |
| 2012-06-20 |  1 |
+------------+----+
```

No magic involved.

Comment: That CREATE results in: `Error Code: 1075. Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key.`

Comment: @RichardKing: Oh? Not for me, what version are you using? Tested on 5.1.51-log, have used it on way older mysql versions too (since mysql 3). Table is MyISAM.

Comment: Thank you. Using the `ENGINE=MyISAM` solved my problem.

Comment: @JohanSoderberg that's a perfect way to solve the problem, but how to do this with  innoDB engine? can we ?

Answer (score 0):

In trigger:
SELECT ID FROM `your_table` WHERE `Date` = DATE(NOW()) INTO max_id;
must be:
SELECT max(ID) FROM `your_table` WHERE `Date` = NEW.key_field INTO max_id;

but better is lock by key.
this is better for concurrent inserts on innodb.